# How can I calculate response time and throughput for large no.of threads

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

Given is jmeter generated summary report for 10 threads(concurrent request).

Can we calculate and find response time and throughput for 50 threads from the report we got for 10 users. I have to run load test of an rest api which trigger email and sms notifications. for which i wanted to know if their any way to find the approx response time and throughput for 50 threads if we have report for 10 threads.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption will be accurate only in the case if linear dependency between number of users and throughput. In the absolute majority of cases you won't be able to predict the metrics values even using a set of previous results, not having only one test scenario.

So the only way to see that will be throughput and response time for 50 concurrent users is to run test with 50 concurrent users. If you are not in position to ramp-up extra virtual users there are [still some things you still can test on a scaled down environment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test) like:

1. Code and Database Interaction
2. External Service Calls
3. Load Allocation
4. [Monitoring the Application Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
5. Run a [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing)